# pdf link not working in iframe

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have a jsp where an iframe is defined like below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<iframe src="http://def.abc.com/service/abcrequester?id=111&name=empDetails" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

The above I frame will load a page with pdf links like

pdf1
pdf2
....
....
If we click on any of the link it should open that pdf in the same window. But it is showing blank page. But if we right click and open in new window then pdf is getting displayed.

Tested in firefox and IE 11. Both the places same behaviour. If we change the browser mode to "Enterprise mode" then pdf is getting displayed in the same window.

Can someone help me in this.

Comment: Same problem occurred for me. If you get PDF file as base64 String or you can change to base64 String the following may help. `<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,${base64PdfText}" type="application/pdf" width="980" height="800"></object>`

Answer (score -1):

simple method in html is just link your pdf in iframe.. e.g.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/example.pdf" width="800px" height="600px" ></iframe>
```

Close the iframe tag is must important.

Comment: I can't do that as the pdf links page will be rendered dynamically from other service. You can observe the src attribute of iframe

Comment: okay .. Actually that is not possible. If you want to click and open pdf in same iframe you should use jquery and e.g. onclick of link change the src of iframe but also remeber that absolute path of pdf file will be used

Comment: ok. But the same functionality was working before 1 month. Its a very old application. We are not sure this was started behaving like this after automatic browser upgrade. As you suggested I directly kept one of the pdf path in the src even then it is not displaying. The same path if we place it in browser directly we were able to see the pdf.

Comment: Can you give me a absolute path  of pdf as shown in my answer

Comment: sorry, as this is a banking project. I am not permitted to share